# Invalid Exception when host web api on azure app service

Tags: c#, azure

My code web api work fine on local host but when I publish on Azure, it response a JSON like this:

```
    {
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Keyword not supported: 'metadata'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)\r\n   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeList(JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable values, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract collectionContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeValue(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonContract valueContract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal(JsonWriter jsonWriter, Object value, Type objectType)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStream(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter.WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, Object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler.<WriteBufferedResponseContentAsync>d__1b.MoveNext()"
  }
}
```

Example result on local:

```
{
  "ID": 0,
  "Code": "string",
  "QDTCReceiveDate": "2019-06-28T10:23:33.087Z",
  "QDTCNumber": "string",
  "QDTCSignDate": "2019-06-28T10:23:33.087Z",
  "Status": "string",
  "OrganizationID": 0
}
```

Connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="DTM_DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DNAManagementModel.csdl|res://*/Models.DNAManagementModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.DNAManagementModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tcp:hainat1.database.windows.net,1433;initial catalog=DTM_DB;user id=blahblah;password=blahblah;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

So what can I do to resolve the problem?

Comment: `"Keyword not supported: 'metadata'."` Are you passing that up?

Comment: There are quite a few pointers in there... `The 'ObjectContent'1' type failed to serialize the response body` and `Keyword not supported: 'metadata'` for instance. Did you serialize to Json locally as well?

Comment: yes, and it work fine on localhost

Comment: You copy/pasted your login credentials in your `connectionString`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. It in the connection string and in the azure. I need to change so that it can use in the entity framework i use in the project

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/15f742a8-f3e4-447d-b24e-3305a72da963/how-best-to-make-azure-database-connection-string-be-an-ef-connection-string?forum=ssdsgetstarted